# Getting the player jump correctly in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm still learning the basics so please be a bit gentle. I'm working on the movement script of a roll-a-ball game. I've got the rolling around working perfectly fine, but now I'm trying to add the ability to jump.

In my case the "player" is a basic Sphere. What I'm trying to accomplish is that when space is pressed, the ball leaps into the air in the direction it's currently rolling.

This is what I've tried myself, but gave very strange results:

```
float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

if (Input.GetKey("space"))
{
    transform.position += transform.up * 20 * Time.deltaTime;
}

rb.AddForce(movement * speed); //rb = RigidBody
```

This resulted in the ball sometimes jumping in the wrong direction or simply just speeding into some direction without jumping at all. So obviously I'm getting closer, but not quite there yet. Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

*Not looking for a quick fix! Don't learn anything from that.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try at this :)

```
if (Input.GetKey("space"))
{
    rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, yourJumpForce, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

You also might want to fiddle with the gravity settings in the rigidbody to get your desired jump as well!

**EDIT** *Explanation*:

I think it may be because you are applying you movement to your `Rigidbody`, but your jumping method to the `Transform` itself.

A `Rigidbody` is a physics component (see docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html), where a `Transform` is to do with position, rotation and scale.

A jump could be considered a physics problem - therefore altering the jump is to do with physics (`Rigidbody`), not the position (`Transform`). I tend to do all movement code with the `Transform`, as you are moving positions, and do all physics based work with the `Rigidbody`, as you are applying physics to the `GameObject`! :)

Comment: This seems to work perfectly fine. Thanks. But can you explain why my solution didn't work? I'm trying to understand what I'm doing instead of just blindly copy / pasting.

Comment: Awesome. I think I can work with that. Thanks a lot again! :) Btw just for funs: I did manage to make it multiplayer over the internet. Ppl can just join with their own ball and start rolling around xDD

Comment: Great stuff, I've taken the comments out and included them in my answer instead :)

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer: The jumping into random directions issue could have been caused by the `transform.up`. That vector is the up direction *relative to your current transform*. That's usually the same as the actual up direction, except if you rotate the game object. And as the object happens to be a rolling ball in this case, it's very likely that it's rotated.

You can fix it by using the global up direction instead - either by doing it like in the accepted answer or by using `Vector3.up`.